# Is there a way .gitconfig file consider redirections of the URL's from a file?

Tags: git

We can use `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080` or `git-proxy.sh` file for using git under proxy.

Similarly, Is there a way to place all my re-directions in a file and make the git consider the redirections instead of using `git config --global url."<URL>".insteadOf <URL>`